# Spring Boot Security sets the Origin header to null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I have Spring Cloud Gateway running. I send a request to one of the routes that redirects to another endpoint which is in the same domain. However, while in the redirected page, the Origin header is null and the resources are not loaded since I only allow a specific domain in the cors configuration ("localhost*" in this case).

Spring Boot version '2.7.10'
Spring Cloud version '2021.0.6'

When I remove the Spring Security from the app, interestingly, the Origin header is not set to null in the redirected page. Instead, it is "localhost:8080", which is the actual behavior I want, but with Spring Security. I wonder why this happens and what could be a potential solution to this.